# attempt to index a boolean value (local 'target')

Tags: lua, fivem

I have looked at different ways to fix this but have no understanding at all. I've tried fixing the code in every was possible and still have no success.

```
RegisterServerEvent('housing:attemptsale')
AddEventHandler('housing:attemptsale',
function(args,price,hid,model)
    local src = source
    local user = exports["np-base"]:getModule("Player"):GetUser(src)
    local char = user:getCurrentCharacter()
    local target = exports["np-base"]:getModule("Player"):GetUser(args)
    local targetchar = user:getCurrentCharacter()
    
    if target:getCash() >= price then
        target:removeMoney(price)
        exports.ghmattimysql:execute("UPDATE houses SET `cid` = @cid, `price` = @price, `model` = @model WHERE `id` = @id", {
            ['@cid'] = targetchar.id,
            ['@price'] = price,
            ['@id'] = hid,
            ['@model'] = model
        })
    else
        TriggerClientEvent('DoShortHudText', args, 'You dont got money', 2)
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide any resources on those functiosn you're using there is not much we can do for you.

Actually this is pretty simple.

You're indexing a boolean value local target.

That means your doing something like `target:something()`, `target.something`, `target[something]`.

Here you create `target`:
`local target = exports["np-base"]:getModule("Player"):GetUser(args)`

Then you do this `target:getCash()`. At this point `target` is a boolean, that means it is either `true` or `false`.

So you know `exports["np-base"]:getModule("Player"):GetUser(args)` returned `true` or `false`.

Now you have two options.

- find out why the function returns a boolean and not what you expect and fix that
- don't index `target` if `target` is not indexable.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm new so I'm not sure what you mean by resource?

Comment: a manual, documentation, any link to more source code, anything that would tell us what those functions are you're using. you shouldn't expect people to know every Lua API on this planet in detail and you should not bother them with searching for that information if they want to help